# comparing date value of two separate columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-6

I have two separate columns within the same table in my database. Both of them store date in this format (2010-10-06T13:00:00). I also have a drupal form which I am trying to validate. It collects collects starttime and endtime values from the user and stores it in the database. 
What I am trying to do is to make sure that the time (starttime && endtime) entered by the user does not already exist in the database. The code below is what I have so far but no success..

```
function taxonomy_conflict_validate(&$form, $form_state) {
   $starttime = $form_state[values][field_roomequip_date][0][value];
   $endtime = $form_state[values][field_roomequip_date][0][value2];

   if (mysql_num_rows(db_query("SELECT * FROM 
          content_type_equiproom WHERE 
          field_roomequip_date_value BETWEEN '$startime' AND '$endtime' 
          AND field_roomequip_date_value2 BETWEEN '$startime' AND '$endtime'")))
      {
         form_set_error("Date", t("The time specified is no longer available"));            
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have already had this question answered but i would like to share a useful resource, that may help you in the future.
[Finding available reservation periods](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#577)

This sounds like the type of thing that you are after, the website in particular is a model of common queries for MySQL that has loads of common things that you may need to achieve. An invaluble resource in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you Andy, I was able to find a solution to my problem in the specified link and the new query looks something like this...if (mysql_num_rows(db_query("SELECT * FROM content_type_equiproom WHERE field_roomequip_date_value2 >= '$starttime' AND field_roomequip_date_value <= '$endtime'"))){
   form_set_error("Date", t("The time specified is no longer available"));    
 }

Comment: No problem - its helped me in the past and I like to pass it on whenever I can ;-)